# Can GRASS export an ESRI ASCII?

Tags: grass-gis, export, ascii, esri-ascii-raster

I have a raster in GRASS GIS and want to export it as a ASCII file following the ESRI [format](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm). This is my code

```
r.out.ascii --overwrite input=XX@PERMANENT output="...\XX.asc" null_value=-9999
```

The file generated has the following header

```
north: 3458710
south: 3454500
east: 353030
west: 348740
rows: 421
cols: 429
```

while the ESRI one is

```
NCOLS xxx
NROWS xxx
XLLCORNER xxx
YLLCORNER xxx
CELLSIZE xxx
NODATA_VALUE xxx
```

My only solution has been to manually edit the header, but i want to export multiple files thus the manual process becomes cumbersome. Does anyone know how to automatically export a raster from GRASS as an ESRI ASCII?

Am using this grass

```
GRASS version: 7.6.0                                                            
GRASS SVN revision: r73958                                                      
Build date: 2019-01-17                                                          
Build platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32                                              
GDAL: 2.4.0                                                                     
PROJ.4: 5.2.0                                                                   
GEOS: 3.7.0                                                                     
SQLite: 3.26.0                                                                  
Python: 2.7.14                                                                  
wxPython: 2.8.12.1                                                              
Platform: Windows-10-10.0.16299
```

Comment: r.out.arc will do it in GRASS before version 7, use r.out.gdal in GRASS 7 or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is

```
r.out.gdal input=XX@PERMANENT output="...\XX.asc" format=AAIGrid
```

Comment: You are a legend. It works perfectly, thanks mate!