# Export a DEM from GRASS and import it to ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, grass-gis, export, import

I've been asked to export a raster map DEM as an ESRI ASCII grid file from GRASS and import it into ArcGIS. The issue is once I add this file to ArcMap I do not know how to view DEM as I just have a data layer with an attribute table. I tried the add XY data tool but the subsequent box only allowed me to add the y data in both columns and then led to an error. How can I display the data in this file?

I also tried ASCII to Raster and got the following error message:

ERROR010067: Error in executing grid expression

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311718/can-grass-export-an-esri-ascii

Comment: The answer I needed, thank you!